# gcloud run & Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-admin, google-cloud-run

I have deployed a JVM application to Google cloud run that uses the Firebase Admin SDK to send notifications on Firebase Cloud Messaging.
Everything works fine locally using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. The deployed app, however, throws errors as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Project ID is required to access messaging service. Use a service account credential or set the project ID explicitly via FirebaseOptions. Alternatively you can also set the project ID via the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable.
```

I create the FirebaseMessaging instance as:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(
    FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(
        GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
    ).build()
```

I have deployed the Cloud Run instance with a service account which has admin permissions for Cloud Run.

My understanding is that an application deployed to any GCP service acquires application credentials automatically. Is there a difference for the combination of Cloud Run and Firebase Admin SDK?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. [Query the cloud metadata service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) to find the project ID where your Cloud Run instance is deployed to. This can only be done within Cloud Run - it won't work if you're testing locally.
2. Make the project ID available to Cloud Run in some way during deployment.

An easy way to implement #2 is to put the project ID in the environment for the Admin SDK to automatically pick up.  For example, a shell script:

```
service_id="your-service-id"
project_id="your-project-id"

gcloud run deploy "$service_id" \
    --project "$project_id" \
    --image "..." \
    --platform managed \
    --update-env-vars "GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=$project_id"
```

Note the `--update-env-vars` which populates `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Thank you so much for your quick help!
One more question: I can't find out what the difference between --update-env-vars and --set-env-vars is

Comment: The gcloud docs should tell you the difference.  If it's not clear, please post a new question.

Comment: This answer is useful, but it doesn't explain **why** do I need to explicitly set project_id when my app is deployed to Cloud Run/GKE. The Firebase docs says that service account should just work without any additional configuration and even [recommends to do it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters). Quote: *this way of intializing the SDK is strongly recommeneded for applications running on Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, and Cloud Functions*. So I'm confused.